# ADB Shell dumpheap - Unable to open file

Tags: android, shell, adb

I am trying to do some memory analysis using adb dumpheap

I am unable to get it to work, every time is says "unable to open file"

I have tried creating a file and pushing it to the device, I have tried pointing to a device in my own computer. Really frustrated and the documentation doesn't say what it should be.

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/shell.html#shellcommands

```
D:\Users\ME\Desktop>adb shell am dumpheap com.my.process logfile.txt
Error: Unable to open file: logfile.txt
```

The file does exist already in the location.
Can anyone please help? I am trying to analyse apps which I do not have the source code for so can not use DDMS memory monitor.

Thanks

Comment: When I try am dumpheap, I get `java.lang.SecurityException: Process not debuggable` exception and the created log file is empty. Are you sure you don't get any errors while trying to dump?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to save to logfile.txt.  But the filename that dumpheap wants is a file on the device.  Try an absolute path that everyone should be able to write to.  For me this worked:

```
./adb shell am dumpheap 1234 /mnt/sdcard/my_heap
```